# How I can change map in the datamaps to an image of world map?

Tags: javascript, angular, datamaps

I want to change the map in the datamaps to a svg image. so that I can change it to different map as needed at a later stage. Is it possible to do that or do I need to change the code in the datamap to change the map to a different map ? or is there way I can hide some of the country in the world map ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been able to solve the issue using the dataURL and get the desired results

```
 this.worldMap = new Datamap({
    element: this.worldMapElementRef.nativeElement,
    responsive: true,
    scope: 'world',
    aspectRatio: 0.60,
    fills: {
        defaultFill: '#22496e',
        'color-type-1': '#ffdd00'
    },
    geographyConfig: {
        dataUrl: '../../../../assets/world.topo.json',
        popupOnHover: true,
        highlightOnHover: false,
        borderWidth:1,
        borderOpacity: 1,
        borderColor: '#22496e',
    }
});
```